# $\mathbb Z_n[x]$, $x+(n-1)$ is a factor of $x^m+(n-1)$ for all $m$ and $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Prove that: in $\mathbb Z_3[x]$, $x+2$ is a factor of $x^m+2$. In $\mathbb Z_n[x]$, $x+(n-1)$ is a factor of $x^m+(n-1)$ for all $m$ and $n$.

You can use long division and get that $x^m+2=(x+2)(x^{m-1}+...+x+1)$. Does this prove that $x+2$ is then a factor or do I need to prove something more?

Similarly, using long division on $x^m+(n-1)=(n-1)(x^{m-1}+...+x+1)$ (I believe).

Comment: It depends on what you consider a proof: For general $m$ strictly speaking you need an inductive argument to show that the long division algorithm does what you say it does. If you need a proof with that level of formality, it's probably easier to apply the induction directly to the claim itself. In that case, you might find it more convenient to write the polynomials instead as $x - 1$ and $x^m - 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The natural surjective homomorphism

$\phi_n: \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z_n \tag1$

induces a homomorphism, also surjective, and also denoted here by $\phi_n$,

$\phi_n: \Bbb Z[x] \to \Bbb Z_n[x]. \tag 2$

Now in $\Bbb Z[x]$, we have

$x^m - 1 = (x - 1)(x^{m -1} + x^{m - 2} + \ldots + 1);  \tag 3$

thus

$\phi_n(x^m - 1) = \phi_n((x - 1)(x^{m -1} + x^{m - 2} + \ldots + 1))$
$= \phi_n(x - 1) \phi_n(x^{m -1} + x^{m - 2} + \ldots + 1). \tag 4$

The image of $x^m - 1$ under $\phi_n$ is

$\phi_n(x^m - 1) = x^m - \phi_n(1) = x^m + (n -1) \in \Bbb Z_n[x], \tag 5$

and the image of $x - 1 \in \Bbb Z[x]$ is

$\phi_n(x - 1) = x - \phi_n(1) = x + (n - 1) \in \Bbb Z_n[x]; \tag 6$

by virtue of (5) and (6), (4) becomes

$x^m + (n - 1) = (x + (n - 1))\phi_n(x^{m -1} + x^{m - 2} + \ldots + 1) \in \Bbb Z_n[x], \tag 7$

which shows that

$x + (n - 1) \mid x^m + (n - 1) \tag 8$

in $\Bbb Z_n[x]$.

Note that we don't need to explicitly present $\phi_n(x^{m -1} + x^{m - 2} + \ldots + 1)$ to complete this result, but it is nevertheless worth noting that

$\phi_n(x^{m -1} + x^{m - 2} + \ldots + 1) = x^{m - 1} + x^{m - 2} + \ldots + 1 \in \Bbb Z_n[x]. \tag 9$

The preceding argument, by virtue of (8), demonstrates that

$x + 2 \mid x^m + 2 \tag{10}$

in $\Bbb Z_3[x]$.  Long division is not really necessary once one has (3), which is easy to verify by direct multiplication:

$(x - 1)(x^{m -1} + x^{m - 2} + \ldots + 1)$
$= x(x^{m -1} + x^{m - 2} + \ldots + x + 1) - 1(x^{m -1} + x^{m - 2} + \ldots + x + 1)$
$= x^m + x^{m -1} + \ldots  + x - x^{m - 1} - \ldots - x -1 = x^m -1 \tag {11}$

(11) avoids the use of long division.

In the above we have made use of the fact that

$n - 1 \equiv -1 \; \mod n. \tag {12}$

Comment: +1, especially for the part about long division being unnecessary once one suspects the right formula.